# A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'List<Widget>' in a const constructor

Tags: flutter

I an new to flutter and learning about rows and column classes. I am trying to add a container to the column, but it's throwing errors.

```
void main(){
  runApp(
    const Myapp()
  );
}

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  const Myapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text 1'),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Text 2'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting errors when I add container as a child in column.
Here are the errors :
[image]

I am following a tutorial and doing the same still getting error.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Remove `const` keyword and it should work.

Comment: And here you can read more on why Container cannot be constant in flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35859

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you should remove

`const`

keyword, and will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use const in there. Column cant be constant. So you have to remove const. Just:

```
void main(){
  runApp(
    const Myapp()
  );
}

class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  const Myapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(/// Here we remove const
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Text 1'),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('Text 2'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```